# Why does angular js not automatically update twice of the number?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am an absolute newbie at angularjs and I am trying to write a code where the html should automatically display twice the number I enter -

This is what my code looks like -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="frmCtrl">
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="number" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{twice}}!</h1>
    </div>

  <script>
    app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("frmCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.number = "2";
        $scope.twice = 2*$scope.number;}
    );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this code does not work at all - when I update the value in the input box, the twice is not updated automatically, although, initially it shows a value of 4 corresponding to twice of 2.

Why is this happening? And is there a better/correct way to achieve what I am trying to achieve here?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way would be, you could modify `twice` value on change of `number` value. For the same you could write `ng-change` function of `number` input field and modify `twice` value from `change` function.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="number" placeholder="Enter a name here" ng-change="updateTwice()"/>
<h1>Hello {{twice}}!</h1>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.updateTwice = function(){
   $scope.twice = 2 * $scope.number;
}
```

---

Another way could be change `twice` as function. Call `twice` on view binding so that will get evaluate on each digest cycle, making sure that whatever displayed on the view is 2 times of `number` ng-model.

```
<h1>Hello {{twice()}}!</h1>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.twice = function(){
 return 2*$scope.number;
}
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much, @pankaj-parkar, that works perfectly. If you don't mind, can you please explain a bit more about the digest cycle?

Comment: @Mortz I'd highly recommend to go through [this article](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/)

Answer (score 1):

Controller is executed only once, and of course $scope.twice is not going to magically update itself. You either make `twice` as a function (see other answer) or set up a watcher, or use `ngChange` directive.

I would use normal javascript [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), it would probably be the most efficient:

```
app.controller("frmCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.number = "2";
  Object.defineProperty($scope, 'twice', {
    get() {
      return 2 * $scope.number
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a scope variable in another, you have use a function.
One option is as above make $scope.twice a function, but when you need that to be a variable you can use ng-change.

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="number" ng-change="calc_twice()" placeholder="Enter a name here">
```

And in the controller:

```
    $scope.twice = "4";
    $scope.calc_twice = function() { $scope.twice = 2 * $scope.number };}
```